# where to add visibility: false in openlayers code?

Tags: javascript, openlayers, openstreetmap

I wanted to know where can I add **visibility: false** in the code below:
Just like in second code ?

```
var line_10 = new OpenLayers.Layer.GML("Line nr-10", 
    "lines/line_10.kml",
    {
        format: OpenLayers.Format.KML,
        style: {strokeWidth: 4, strokeColor: "#f08080", fillOpacity: 1 },
        projection: map.displayProjection
    }
);
```

Second Code:

```
var linja4_2 = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("Line nr-4 stations", {
    projection: map.displayProjection,
    strategies: [new OpenLayers.Strategy.Fixed()],
    protocol: new OpenLayers.Protocol.HTTP({
        url: "/data/linja-nr4.kml",
        format: new OpenLayers.Format.KML({
            extractStyles: true,
            extractAttributes: true
        })
    }),
    visibility: false
});
```

Comment: Try using `setVisibility()` on GML. http://dev.openlayers.org/docs/files/OpenLayers/Layer/GML-js.html#OpenLayers.Layer.GML.setVisibility

Comment: Im sorry but I dont know in which line that should be put. !?

Comment: Outside your code behind the declaration of your variable line_10. I cannot test it here, but I guess this should work: `line_10.setVisibility(false);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I remember correctly I would put the `visibility` here:

```
var line_10 = new OpenLayers.Layer.GML("Line nr-10", 
    "lines/line_10.kml",
    {
        format: OpenLayers.Format.KML,
        style: {strokeWidth: 4, strokeColor: "#f08080", fillOpacity: 1 },
        projection: map.displayProjection
    }, {
        visibility: false
    }
);
```

Or as suggested in the comments:

```
var line_10 = new OpenLayers.Layer.GML("Line nr-10", 
    "lines/line_10.kml",
    {
        format: OpenLayers.Format.KML,
        style: {strokeWidth: 4, strokeColor: "#f08080", fillOpacity: 1 },
        projection: map.displayProjection
    }
);
line_10.setVisibility(false);
```

Comment: You saved me! Adding <base_layer>.setVisibility(false); to my each base layers had a huge performance impact on loading.